# RemoveClass for "img id"?

Tags: jquery, css

Say my foo_image is being appended to the container like so:

```
$container.append("<img id='FooImage' src='foo_image.png' />");
```

In another method I want to delete this FooImage as if it was never appended. I'm not sure how to accomplish this with something solely using `img id`. Hopefully this is a derp question and someone can get an easy answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find and remove based on the id of the element:

```
$("#FooImage").remove();
```

Comment: Both your initial answer and this does the trick. ;) I didn't know the img id could be referenced in the same way as regular id's.

Answer (score 4):

Try `.remove` to remove the element.

```
$('#FooImage').remove();
```